# How to pass drag and dropped file in web app as input to python code?

Tags: python, flask, pdf, web, automation

So, I am trying to build an automation web app where I can upload pdf files, and then a python code will run which extracts certain data from the uploaded pdf files.

I know how to make a python code that takes a pdf from my local system and extracts the required data, but how do I make the code use the uploaded pdf files on the web app?

I plan to deploy this website where the python code can be run on any system using the website, so how exactly do I pass the uploaded file as input to the python code?

Also, will using Flask make it easier to approach this?

Comment: Can you show the code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want to deploy one website, then the end user can access the web page and upload pdf file, web service accept the request and run python script to parse data from uploaded pdf, right?
if above is correct, seems you can save the pdf on the serverside, and deploy another cronjob to monitor the path, if new pdf file reached, can trigger python script running.